# Obtaining the details of users downloading android app

Tags: android

I am making an app for android with no user login. The app allows people to upload photos anonymously. Since the app has some user generated content I wanted to somehow identify the user without having a login. Basically, is it possible to extract the user details from the app store or uniquely identify each account that downloads and posts things in the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To identify the device:

with the image posted on your server you can get the device IMEI number and other details.

> To identify the user:

you can retrieve the email id of the user who is posting the picture with the image
you can get registered emailID from following code

```
Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(context).getAccounts();
String email="";
if(accounts.length > 0)
     email = accounts[0].name;
```

for this you need following permissions

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

Comment: for this I will have to ask the user to login using their email id right?

Comment: no from the above code it will get the user's email id from which the user is connected to google play. you don't have to ask user to enter his/her email ID